# On the verification of an equality of sets

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation

Only one thing is not clear to me.

> **Proposition.**
>   Let $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb {N}}$ a sequence of integrable function no-negative such that $f_{n}\le f_{n+1}$ if
>   \begin{equation}
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Xf_n\;d\lambda=0,
> \end{equation}
>   then 
>   \begin{equation}
> \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n<\infty\quad\text{a.e.}
> \end{equation}

**proof.**
\begin{equation}
0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Xf_n\;d\lambda=\sup_n\int_Xf_n \;d\lambda,
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
\int_Xf_n\;d\lambda=0\quad\text{for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$},
\end{equation}
therefore $f_n=0$ a.e.for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now
\begin{equation}
\lambda(\{x:f_n(x)>0\})=0.
\end{equation}
We observe that
\begin{equation}
\{x:\lim_nf_n(x)>0\}=\cup_n\{x:f_n(x)>0\}\quad(1)
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
\lambda(\{x:\lim_nf_n(x)>0\})=\lambda(\cup_n\{x:f_n(x)>0\})=\lim_n\lambda(\{x:f_n(x)>0\})=0.
\end{equation}
Is it correct to proceed in this way for 1?

If $x\in\cup_n\{x:f_n(x)>0\}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f_{n_0}(x)>0$ $\Rightarrow$  $\sup_n\{f_n(x)>0\}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lim_n f_n(x)=\sup_n\{f_n(x)\}>0$. Then
\begin{equation}
\bigcup_n\{x:f_n(x)>0\}\subseteq \{x:\lim_nf_n(x)>0\}.
\end{equation}
If $x\in\{x:\lim_nf_n(x)>0\}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\sup_n\{f_n(x)\}>0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\exists n_0$ such that $f_{n_0}(x)>0$ $\Rightarrow$ $x\in\cup_n\{x:f_n(x)>0\}$.

Thanks!

Comment: Your argument looks fine, but you can simplify it using that fact that countable union of sets of measure $0$ has measure $0$.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy  Thank you! So I omit that limit and I can immediately say that the measure of union is 0, I did not think about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct.

---

As an aside, you are actually showing that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n = 0 \ \mathrm{a.e.}$. So, perhaps one more line could be added, namely that
$$
\{ x : \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \infty \} \subseteq \{ x : \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) > 0 \},
$$
and from the fact that the measure of any subset of a null set is zero (assuming that $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure here), your proof will be (more) complete.